# Modify namespace from package

Tags: typescript, namespaces

I'm using a type def installed via `@types` that I'd like to modify.

`Q` has a pretty soft `.d.ts` that doesn't allow you to specify the type of the argument passed to `reject` on `Deferred`.  The interface  for `Defferred` looks like this:

```
declare namespace Q {
    // ...
    export interface Deferred<T> {
        promise: Promise<T>;
        resolve(value?: IWhenable<T>): void;
        reject(reason: any): void;
        notify(value: any): void;
        makeNodeResolver(): (reason: any, value: T) => void;
    }
    // ...
}
```

With normal interfaces, you can just create ones with matching names in, say, `global.d.ts` and they're automatically merged in, I can't get this to work with interfaces in namespaces.

What I'd like to do is drop something like this in my `global.d.ts` file:

```
declare namespace Q {
    export interface Deferred<T, R, N> {
        reject(reason: R): void;
        notify(value: N): void;
    }

    export function defer<T, R, N>(): Deferred<T, R, N>;
}
```

And have it merge that interface and function back into the ones in the `Q` `.d.ts` in `@types`.  Testing this by calling `const def = Q.defer<string, string, number()` raises `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
declare namespace Q {
    export interface Deferred<T, E=any, N=any> {
        promise: Promise<T>;
        resolve(value?: IWhenable<T>): void;
        reject(reason: E): void;
        notify(value: N): void;
        makeNodeResolver(): (reason: any, value: T) => void;
    }
}
```

You can't rename the generic parameter `T`, and if you add any extra parameters, they need to have defaults so that other uses of `Deferred` don't require the extras.

---

#### Update 1

@Sandy Gifford [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195975/modify-namespace-from-package#comment77360325_45196241):

> For brevity I left out the modification to bits of `Q` that used `Deferred`. I've edited my question to include them. This still didn't seem to work - calling `Q.defer<string, string, number>()` still raises an exception.

You still have to give default parameters to any extra generic types you add to the `defer` function.  I don't know exactly how your project is laid out, but something like this works for me, with module augmentation:

```
import { Q } from 'q'

declare module 'q' {
  namespace Q {

    interface Deferred<T, R=any, N=any> {
      reject(reason: R): void;
      notify(value: N): void;
    }

    function defer<T, R=any, N=any>(): Deferred<T, R, N>;
  }
}

Q.defer<string, string, number>();
```

Comment: For brevity I left out the modification to bits of `Q` that used `Deferred`.  I've edited my question to include them.  This still didn't seem to work - calling `Q.defer<string, string, number>()` still raises an exception.

Comment: Update 1 made a lot of progress!  Only change is to lose the `namespace` between the `module` and the `interface`/`function`.  Unfortunately `module`s don't seem to merge, and everything that isn't mentioned explicitly in my override is getting overwritten.  I'm beginning to think that I should either uninstall the `@type` and use my own `.d.ts`, or just open a pull request on definitelytyped.

Comment: I agree: using your own type declaration file is probably the cleanest solution for you.